# knife cookbook upload (ERROR: internal server error)

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-solo, knife

Been trying for hours to setup my own chef server on ec2. I launched an ubuntu 12.04 instance and installed open source chef server using the deb package. Then I associated an elastic ip, setup a host in route 53, updated the hostname. Also updated the ssl cert and key in .../ngnix/ca., restarted the chef server and ran chef-server-ctl reconfigure followed by chef-server-ctl test. All tests passed.

Then I followed this tutorial: http://blog.afistfulofservers.net/post/2011/03/16/a-brief-chef-tutorial-from-concentrate/

Just trying to upload a simple ntp cookbook.

```
knife cookbook upload ntp -VV
```

and this get this output.
please help!

```
`    ubuntu@chef:~/workspace/chef-repo$ knife cookbook upload ntp -VV
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_request
    DEBUG: Signing the request as rayhwang
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Initiating GET to https://chef.originalfunction.com/cookbooks?num_versions=all
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: Accept: application/json
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2014-06-19T17:12:14Z
    DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: O3rGoHt5f9pv8VMIPQF71lKugcFCuLW0bAU05Tlus+vIWhk0yd/JIvYPU9l0
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: pkkNVlPHEu5eCHvi2W8kJWVqaSBb6PwtUv5nPM/oeuI8lWpr9uUlUKh6vcr8
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: n5Q0jA2NqjBisRSRn6ROriJis0x4xuReXj1y12234wOjDAa7xcT/ssEXzjNw
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: ZFwmr95cDEA7FuOgtAGt0RWib8ZkdWYerGbW2n1lv4pKMAl9c6fDgOuN1z9A
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: 1hhvo0l0hH/q/DcRhePG8rBR67iN4KcsashiyMOVbM9qyDSHUfk99OrjHYys
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: UCWvq3569li6bBRqCx1a20Ze2kuHKvMxhasjSwcaig==
    DEBUG: HOST: chef.originalfunction.com:443
    DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: 1d230738-c4b4-4d69-b71c-12d4203cf5f8
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 200 OK
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:14 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 2
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-ops-api-info: flavor=osc;version=11.0.2;erchef=1.4.0
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Content-Length validated correctly.
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
    Uploading ntp          [0.1.0]
    DEBUG: No chefignore file found at /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/.chef/../cookbooks/chefignore no files will be ignored
    INFO: Validating ruby files
    DEBUG: Ruby file /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/.chef/../cookbooks/ntp/recipes/default.rb is unchanged, skipping syntax check
    DEBUG: Ruby file /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/.chef/../cookbooks/ntp/metadata.rb is unchanged, skipping syntax check
    INFO: Validating templates
    DEBUG: Template /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/.chef/../cookbooks/ntp/templates/default/ntp.conf.erb is unchanged, skipping syntax check
    INFO: Syntax OK
    INFO: Saving ntp
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_request
    DEBUG: Signing the request as rayhwang
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Initiating POST to https://chef.originalfunction.com/sandboxes
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: Content-Type: application/json
    DEBUG: Accept: application/json
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: trgzi7/cKkm3nQVgxJylZYUyXQo=
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: fJSAIpj1nQMBCRiDxjMfjiZb4+0JO4G4H8EKIvdNOxtpZfY0hyQm0CTRhXnd
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: dwmcgy2aiPYSQjxoav1UPx4S+kVNEhJDgWOR5g0tFlucNZwL7iHik/qPCrXm
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: pUoJ+TUiCWpBy4W9NGPsfqE4WHcNm6x+d/V/EV36hdPzdkAO9YmB1QRxIQrd
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: Jy6VukLzLGdPzcpSDDmA2u27AtPhI2qvJlH5xHT6Nb3fiT8pQCcdH7YWNbC/
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: MUm2wMZuSrNGVEgBCt/3ZSU16SMEp0BlXGdEoxwjoq4iiWNhm8CQgg57XjMz
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: pcpNk6WDgBIChp8gshclhkLtn619CJePcKnIU5C47g==
    DEBUG: HOST: chef.originalfunction.com:443
    DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: 1d230738-c4b4-4d69-b71c-12d4203cf5f8
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 215
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 201 Created
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 1772
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-ops-api-info: flavor=osc;version=11.0.2;erchef=1.4.0
    DEBUG: location: http://chef.originalfunction.com:443/sandboxes/00000000000002353a650204d5f4d7eb
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Content-Length validated correctly.
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
    INFO: Uploading files
    INFO: Uploading /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/cookbooks/ntp/recipes/default.rb (checksum hex = bbefe633613e76a79797713ac99604ff) to https://chef.originalfunction.com:443/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-bbefe633613e76a79797713ac99604ff?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=puzm8RkYYnH%2BdOlsa1k1pl3zT1k%3D
    INFO: Uploading /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/cookbooks/ntp/templates/default/ntp.conf.erb (checksum hex = 1a2e519cdc43799100bf074f4b96a50b) to https://chef.originalfunction.com:443/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-1a2e519cdc43799100bf074f4b96a50b?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=w6RU9GAtWATjeEAYtB05JxrGbA0%3D
    INFO: Uploading /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/cookbooks/ntp/README.md (checksum hex = d3e0411a88dfd6905fe57e5e6975e630) to https://chef.originalfunction.com:443/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-d3e0411a88dfd6905fe57e5e6975e630?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=C7vKsEE1F%2B1j76DtI5385ZULMEs%3D
    INFO: Uploading /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/cookbooks/ntp/CHANGELOG.md (checksum hex = 43e746152c1a63002b6a306a94666368) to https://chef.originalfunction.com:443/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-43e746152c1a63002b6a306a94666368?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=vm2cI5AVzNIipkRZGnRH%2BRK874g%3D
    INFO: Uploading /home/ubuntu/workspace/chef-repo/cookbooks/ntp/metadata.rb (checksum hex = 8af72e56cfd5f3aedb1d5a5c77ba8ab7) to https://chef.originalfunction.com:443/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-8af72e56cfd5f3aedb1d5a5c77ba8ab7?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=DnoM16WYVq4VhbjsiSvTZWaFabQ%3D
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Initiating PUT to https://chef.originalfunction.com/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-1a2e519cdc43799100bf074f4b96a50b?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=w6RU9GAtWATjeEAYtB05JxrGbA0%3D
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: content-type: application/x-binary
    DEBUG: content-md5: Gi5RnNxDeZEAvwdPS5alCw==
    DEBUG: accept: application/json
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Userid: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Timestamp: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Content-Hash: B7IhBLQbRkoCUtlseIpTx5ODlNM=
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-1: UEOLzo2dr12JKXgOXZyxxBu4qzMebcTD15tS5dLWIRhhKkhfs7JWToDBMEqM
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-2: UdPTKjJI+/hUo9CIdngFcshXejMuVQQ808hoNA35VSr5tKA7rKXpEKu3p1X6
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-3: g6NC1R/SKWPAGhYA4m6rwyMsrsZ1ETh8WR27GrKAJ1Jgqg89GyR6Oessub+V
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-4: rOFy3kNpM19NbESqYaL3nMzZWep/TbUu0j8KaUkZM5YFvcsc3TBGk5lZYEFd
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-5: iwwNXmDMIN4r5e1lZv7BtEws4qJCEgLBjaS1oReQO4qqffwZxcsj1ygHPer1
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-6: JReBLIqLlj4t7NMU22EkBZL1bfMarDdOsO9Ix+soBg==
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 275
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Initiating PUT to https://chef.originalfunction.com/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-d3e0411a88dfd6905fe57e5e6975e630?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=C7vKsEE1F%2B1j76DtI5385ZULMEs%3D
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: content-type: application/x-binary
    DEBUG: content-md5: 0+BBGojf1pBf5X5eaXXmMA==
    DEBUG: accept: application/json
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Userid: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Timestamp: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Content-Hash: DE1oiQN0K9neW6A+7u/2NzQ/W4o=
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-1: fiCtNCKht0VPOvXMBPFmUz7+uQ2qSRk6U1B8uoqxzvvvTXR/KduDweyHI51y
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-2: GN6dpyxisDTfebYsQLnCzmtDlhlj5lEtQ9GUFxpPjEDSInQO3ZVohd3MsDGC
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-3: R2d/xvONhA7RJgnP3uPLR2VcXsafjSCycGOf4Ul5A366Ys3NTW/wS0gTH0t4
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-4: lGactDkxHh0EnQq41K8j82waTnYsaGBci9NRTYxUgHPHLT8llX/2gke4KMy0
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-5: S2oEBWhZnOSn1A3Js8ofUmCJ6UvQBIomZDjisDvKARZVKMbE/4jHPw8IsDqf
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-6: mVps4JZJ5AnBg/MGTBSb0kwE1wJV35m7Bl8pMncErw==
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 1424
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Initiating PUT to https://chef.originalfunction.com/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-43e746152c1a63002b6a306a94666368?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=vm2cI5AVzNIipkRZGnRH%2BRK874g%3D
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: content-type: application/x-binary
    DEBUG: content-md5: Q+dGFSwaYwArajBqlGZjaA==
    DEBUG: accept: application/json
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Userid: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Timestamp: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Content-Hash: xrD6SmanZIPZariIevDsxEdIYwc=
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-1: FBv6fegrNfG6hzo9JHfXAUWYgNE8jYExuLEpKCPL9R3j65k64/gTvMHAvzDt
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-2: vZSmZOl2y/AekvxZgcpQcfnODn+0ol2cXcoQUjuK9fTy0BDskUHEp+ZT0FUE
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-3: 2VylMn8O2rmDC3yuvGk50+DUXoRmEcIG+R0kZ1HAtO17wv713GYZ7knOML9u
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-4: bIz9HiuMKKhfhTHjO18cDPlDkZIimjkowlhNQl3rTBqEqCaQ4zdWOUqWrHeY
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-5: 429PuSxb0aghzEjcAxAMvgyXb/7pijPRFgyMjXbiTPO1qIz6I/hAFxyoHWY5
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-6: NwbuwIYlFQyV4RYj5BwYBhmuKZnUmqmPlj0NsUHYZA==
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 439
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Initiating PUT to https://chef.originalfunction.com/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-8af72e56cfd5f3aedb1d5a5c77ba8ab7?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=DnoM16WYVq4VhbjsiSvTZWaFabQ%3D
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: content-type: application/x-binary
    DEBUG: content-md5: ivcuVs/V867bHVpcd7qKtw==
    DEBUG: accept: application/json
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Userid: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Timestamp: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Content-Hash: XoOuSZFMGBbUEtZkO+3JXkPjraY=
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-1: RJmE+qqBpN6AFc0a4tJ1HQtq9zu72tgPS1xwTcxUvC8nJhdNXJdolWBsTV1y
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-2: Wl6OuqMbcThaXFnhYguj+mq7M1GGgwHf6onzScer0z43JoFPAGLgNRwvsBUM
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-3: eA9XGsi5nX6rqbTeCClRujF2zBBKxfjzgQKlKZaQT5i+Tkmxi+JW6eGcdnCR
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-4: mwk11NM95dIIRh/pI72Tr0K17i6kKzHLnJjSlP15dyoUxnLu4PsydIXMCtqH
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-5: maVl8Z6qjPPB1EehqaUfOwRA5henKn55lrsBzgf9IQz3Hoi8MNht9xY4mDaB
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-6: QOQdighUY5/3Z5BAj7JvYcSbPIthuKdM86ZPtd3SBw==
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 290
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Initiating PUT to https://chef.originalfunction.com/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-bbefe633613e76a79797713ac99604ff?AWSAccessKeyId=ee81637c54a846e63c3690be759203a8fca05c93&Expires=1403198835&Signature=puzm8RkYYnH%2BdOlsa1k1pl3zT1k%3D
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: content-type: application/x-binary
    DEBUG: content-md5: u+/mM2E+dqeXl3E6yZYE/w==
    DEBUG: accept: application/json
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Userid: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Timestamp: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Content-Hash: As+jO7AROTDuK2wG6/heed0nbjE=
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-1: lfF8Jy5Ayz5vKcqV/hACwJzALiXkoqAbqkEmhtJsICX/3v2srJ71JaZoUczk
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-2: yxnESOarrgjeQClX9WMOgb4or/J5YiWDiEOEr5+fDfhv+I6ZxLYr9DvsDMnm
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-3: oXbgqyPrw35+jwmXnk7YQ4/GRadENWfBTkeUEvbTJ1X5QxBsgRGKKHO4zL9t
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-4: qWlJMdIXesKLWl1+hGuXZ9pUA33U0QqGPBCp+b5MxGUPHhqoYda9yB9CL8SG
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-5: PJ19tFBB6Gblll1+4ObEaYkenrPxutOj8EXfE7GPiWcPfzsY9ZWL/m0adyW6
    DEBUG: X-Ops-Authorization-6: qYCKOfaqFRM2eFARQD+MFwcNv90Wbbl2oIxXsl3c4A==
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 322
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 204 No Content
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 0
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-amz-request-id: g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABXtiAAMFL2IABVJQ
    DEBUG: etag: 0+BBGojf1pBf5X5eaXXmMA==
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 204 No Content
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 0
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-amz-request-id: g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABXtiAAMFL2IABVqE
    DEBUG: etag: Gi5RnNxDeZEAvwdPS5alCw==
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 204 No Content
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 0
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-amz-request-id: g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABXtiAAMFL2IABZs7
    DEBUG: etag: Q+dGFSwaYwArajBqlGZjaA==
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 204 No Content
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 0
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-amz-request-id: g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABXtiAAMFL2IABbo2
    DEBUG: etag: ivcuVs/V867bHVpcd7qKtw==
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 204 No Content
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 0
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-amz-request-id: g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABXtiAAMFL2IABzNL
    DEBUG: etag: u+/mM2E+dqeXl3E6yZYE/w==
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: Committing sandbox
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_request
    DEBUG: Signing the request as rayhwang
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_request
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
    DEBUG: Initiating PUT to https://chef.originalfunction.com/sandboxes/0000000000008170b3f221f9b2144a84
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: Content-Type: application/json
    DEBUG: Accept: application/json
    DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
    DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
    DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: rayhwang
    DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2014-06-19T17:12:15Z
    DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: oMRtV6loUDnbKJuGcW6nqBbF8ww=
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: DoblHxKdB3zjRPyuNULSlTXmusmy+TL+gQ/3+TWv1yPejJvaNt46DutW5//n
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: jfBh+Oot1l5mWfIwall2MH7BraHveavQCE1Thr4p2JoJff3cPsX1yiWhP5jd
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: cnmO1VNdwXFvgyrT7/2NOcicp+KDgv1tZ/JongFvVPvc0WYnR4mhk8+GGgmP
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: pVICKVUN1PM7fqhiEW17jN4yNrIQhGfW8jQLDnfYTT0GXbC4Mhoc2paJcGUj
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: /BZiqfFgF1Ymlh1vFR7yU+mfE3b2pA1aKyajWdNSekBcGQHkdknVuZxMDIp4
    DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: fv+NYIfIR6QKT2Opj+BsCjnctUEL+UxQyjfbieTwqQ==
    DEBUG: HOST: chef.originalfunction.com:443
    DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: 1d230738-c4b4-4d69-b71c-12d4203cf5f8
    DEBUG: Content-Length: 21
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
    DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
    DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    DEBUG: server: nginx/1.4.4
    DEBUG: date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:12:15 GMT
    DEBUG: content-type: application/json
    DEBUG: content-length: 36
    DEBUG: connection: close
    DEBUG: x-ops-api-info: flavor=osc;version=11.0.2;erchef=1.4.0
    DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
    DEBUG: Content-Length validated correctly.
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_response
    DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
    INFO: HTTP Request Returned 500 Internal Server Error: internal service error
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!': 500 "Internal Server Error" (Net::HTTPFatalError)
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http.rb:143:in `request'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http.rb:116:in `put'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:105:in `upload_cookbooks'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_upload.rb:243:in `upload'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_upload.rb:129:in `block in run'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_upload.rb:126:in `each'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_upload.rb:126:in `run'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:492:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:174:in `run'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:135:in `run'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/knife:30:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/knife:30:in `<main>'`
```

Comment: What do the server logs say?

Comment: Also, you have a default Chef Server installation with the default passwords on a publicly accessible instance...

Comment: @sethvargo  sorry, i scratched the whole instance and started over. i have made some interesting discoveries. so from a clean install and configuration. everything works! EXCEPT. the browser complains about a self-signed certificate. "https://chef.*******.com/".

Comment: the moment i update the crt, key, and conf in the ngnix/ca, reconfigure. the browser stops complaining, everything checks out. but then cookbook upload errors out and chef-server-ctl test fails.

Comment: Have you reconfigured the chef server after changing the cert?

Comment: yup. reconfigured and restarted. the certs are validating correctly in the browser. but then knife fails..

Comment: apparently there's a ticket open for this   [link](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5144)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is a bug in the open source Chef Server and has been reported on the Chef issue tracker as [CHEF-5144](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5144)